# Android Scrolling of a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, scrollview

In my layout i had a `RelativeLayout`, 
its children are a `ScrollView` at top, `EditText` and a `Button` at bottom of the screen
and in the ScrollView there is a `LinearLayout` 
i am getting some data and adding it to the LinearLayout dynamically
and scrolling the view with `Scrollview.scrollTO()` method

but the problem is the scrollview is occupying fullhieght of the screen i.e the data is also displaying under the edittext and button

Is there any way that the scrollview can be limited to the top of the edittext and button ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" 
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="461dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
    android:onClick="check"
    android:text="@string/btnlb" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_above="@+id/button1".. Write this in scrollview property

Comment: when i add this statement , It raised an Exception saying that android.widget.button can not be casted to android.widget.linearlayout--@ShabbirDhangot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just set your scrollview layout_above attribute to the id of either the button or the edittext. However, for this you must declare the edittext/button above where you declare the scrollview (I think?). Eg something like this (I haven't tested)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
    android:onClick="check"
    android:text="@string/btnlb" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/button1"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" 
    >

    <LinearLayout
    ....
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: scrollview should have height and width of match_parent, not wrap_content